# NullPointerException at boundservice.setAlarm(cal)

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I am trying to set alarm and notify user at the user's specified time.
But I get **NullPointerException** at **boundService.setAlarm(cal)**.
I checked this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13379580/java-lang-nullpointerexception-showing-at-mboundservice-setalarmc) with a similar question but the solutions did not help me.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance!

**DateAndTimePickerActivity**

```
public class DateAndTimePickerActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    OnClickListener {
    public Calendar cal;
     private ScheduleClient scheduleClient;
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    scheduleClient = new ScheduleClient(this);
    scheduleClient.doBindService();
   }
    @Override
  private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yearSelected,
            int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth,int ) {
        year = yearSelected;
        month = monthOfYear;
        day = dayOfMonth;

    }
};
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
    // the callback received when the user "sets" the TimePickerDialog in
    // the dialog
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int min) {
        hour = hourOfDay;
        minute = min;
        }
        };
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

     cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(year, month, day);
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        scheduleClient.setAlarmForNotification(cal); //NullPointerException 

}
}
```

**ScheduleClient**

```
public class ScheduleClient {

private ScheduleService boundService;
private Context context;
 private boolean isBound;
RemindMe remindme;
public ScheduleClient(Context context) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
}

public void doBindService() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    context.bindService(new Intent(context,ScheduleService.class), Connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    isBound=true;

}
 private ServiceConnection Connection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        boundService=((ScheduleService.ServiceBinder) service).getService();

    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        boundService=null;

    }

 };



public void doUnbindService() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (isBound) {
        // Detach our existing connection.
        context.unbindService(Connection);
        isBound = false;


}

   }
     public void setAlarmForNotification(Calendar cal) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       boundService.setAlarm(cal); //NullPointerException
   }


}
```

Comment: where schedule client is initialized?

Comment: Please check my edited code

Comment: boundService seems to be null, check with a log if it is well initialized in onServiceConnected

Comment: Put a logger or breakpoint in `onServiceDisconnected` and check if it ever gets called prior your `onClick` which sets the `scheduleClient.setAlarmForNotification(cal);`